# question about span

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, control-theory

Let $\dot x = Ax$ and $S$ be an orthogonal basis of null space of $A$. Does it imply that $x$ converge to a point in $\operatorname{span}\{S\}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is only try is all remaining eigenvalues has a negative real part and for the eigenvalues of zero the algebraic multiplicity is the same as the geometric multiplicity. All other eigenvalues have to have a negative real part to ensure that all other modes decay to zero, for example
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
can blow up to infinity. And the algebraic multiplicity has to be equal to the geometric multiplicity to ensure that the eigenvector of the eigenvalue of zero is actually a stationary point, for example
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
can also increase linearly in time, however the solution will converge to the span of the generalized eigenvectors of eigenvalue of zero (but not necessary to a point).

Answer (score 0):

No. You don't specify whether you're asking about the limit of $x(t)$ as $t\to\infty$ or $t\to-\infty$; for a counterexample to both let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$.